# Where can I ask a question about dealing with a problem with my next-door neighbor?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Suppose I have a problem with my next-door neighbor and could use some advice on how to approach them and address the problem. If my problem were with a co-worker instead of a neighbor, [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) would be the best place (and, in my experience, the users would give wonderful advice). If I wanted to look into legal recourse, I could try [Law](http://law.stackexchange.com). But I'm looking for advice on how to talk to the neighbor about the problem in an agreeable, non-hostile fashion.

Is there any Stack Exchange site that would be an appropriate place to ask a question about dealing with a neighbor problem?

Comment: What is the problem about, if I may ask? Context can help here.

Comment: Next-door neighbor has a dog. This dog poops in our lawn. My upstairs neighbor (who owns the property) sometimes throws the dog mines back into the next-door neighbor's yard. Apparently one of these dark projectiles was actually cat poop. Next-door neighbor yells at me to stop throwing their dog's poop into their yard or I'll "*regret it*". He does this while I have my toddler in one arm and groceries in the other.

Comment: [lifehacks.se] might yield interesting answers... but I'm not sure how on-topic it would be though.

Comment: There's definitely no community for that style of question - the answers would probably be far too opinion based. I'd walk up to that punk and explain that while you're not the one returning his dog's "presents", he should watch his tone when speaking with you. In other words, stand up for yourself. Additionally, buy a nice, large bag of cayenne pepper, and sprinkle it around the property, in the areas where this dog typically does his business. Believe you me, it'll be the last time he comes sniffing around. (i didn't even talk to my neighbor, just deployed the cayenne. Dog never returned.)

Comment: Martial Arts SE? /s

Comment: @AndreiROM Thanks for the cayenne pepper suggestion, I might give that a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This probably won't fit anywhere on the network. It's an opinion question, and Stack Exchange doesn't generally field those very well.

The closest one, at least in regards to dealing with the dog, would be the [Pets Beta Site.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/674/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-another-dog-from-pooping-on-our-grass)

Not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange, which isn't necessarily a bad thing.

---

If you have an idea for a new site you could see if there's any support for it on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), but I doubt a Dealing-With-Jerks.SE will gain much ground.

Comment: Dealing-with-Jerks.SE might not, but Neighborhood.SE or Diplomacy.SE *might*. But regardless, I see your point.

Comment: I would expect diplomacy.se to be about politics, @mouseas

Comment: @JanDvorak Well, isn't dealing with problematic people a major part of politics?

Answer (score 7):

We now have an [Interpersonal Skills site](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) it has a [neighbor](/questions/tagged/neighbor) tag that has 76 questions. The site's help centre says the site is for

> Questions focusing on using and improving your own interpersonal skills, in an attempt to resolve specific problems or prevent problems from occurring when having specific interactions with people.

Which sounds like what you're looking for. However do read their help centre article about [questions being specific enough to be answered](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first and maybe look at some of their existing well received questions to check yours would fit.

Comment: Yeah this appears to be the best bet, but I really hope OP has resolved the problems by now. ;)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard - I didn't ever solve the problem, but I did move away for a new job like 6 or 7 years ago, so...

Comment: @Martin lol that is unexpected, how did you notice my comment?! ;) Anyway, glad it was sorted in a way, neighbor problems can become really nasty.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Unread Inbox message, notifying me of a new answer on my old, old question.

Comment: @Martin rare to have people active for so long, cheers! :)